# boxy.confirm don't wait for confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery, boxy

In case the close `(X)` is pressed, Boxy doesn't wait for a confirmation. Below is an example describing my problem:

```
$('form .close').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    Boxy.confirm("Are you sure ?", function() {
        alert('ok');
    });
    return false;
});
```

However, when the `OK` button is clicked, everything works as expected.

Why does this not work as expected in case the `(X)` is pressed?

Comment: `Boxy.confirm` is async unlike native `confirm`. Your code will continue execution without waiting for user to click OK. 
As for form submit. There is a special treatment for this case (bind on form.submit event, prevent default behaviour, manually submit for in passed callback). Sure there is no such things for 'form closing' whatever it is.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this example that I made for you: http://jsfiddle.net/972ak/

```
$('form .close').click(function(event) {

            Boxy.confirm("Are you sure ?", function() {
                alert('ok');
            });
            return false;

    });
```

Boxy documentation says:

Boxy.confirm(message, callback, options)
Displays a modal, non-closeable dialog displaying a message with OK and Cancel buttons. Callback will only be fired if user selects OK.

http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/boxy/

Comment: How would this help? :) Your example works the same as the original code.

Comment: I am saying that Boxy cancel button (close button) does not fire the confirm callback.

Comment: And how this is related to the OPs question 'Boxy doesn't wait for a confirmation'?

Answer (score 0):

As I have already mentioned in my comment `Boxy.confirm` is async unlike native `confirm`. Your code will continue its execution without waiting for user to click OK or Cancel. That is why you need to perform the actual action inside confirm callback.

Consider the following code.

```
$('form .close').click(function(e){
    var form = $(this).closest('form');

    Boxy.confirm('Are you sure?', function() {
        form.remove(); //remove it only if user confirmed.    
    });

    form.append('<p>Close was clicked.</p>');

})
```

This code will append message every time user clicks close link. But the form will be actually removed only if user confirmed the action.

http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/972ak/4/